# How do i make singleton class as delegator in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, singleton, ios10

I have a singleton class as shown in below code snippet .

```
protocol EmpLoginDelegate {
    func empLoginSuccess()
    func empLoginFailed()
}         
class CommunicationModule {
    static let sharedInstance = CommunicationModule()
    private init() {
    }
    var empLoginDelegate:EmpLoginDelegate?

    func test(){
           self.empLoginDelegate?.empLoginSuccess()
    } 
}
```

My delegate class is shown in below code snippet.

```
extension LoginViewController: EmpLoginDelegate{
  func empLoginSuccess(){
    wrongAttempts = 0
    loginSuccess = true
    print("EmpLoginIsSuccess")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "attendanceView", sender: self)

  }
  func empLoginFailed(){
    wrongAttempts = wrongAttempts + 1
    userNameTextField.shake(count: 3, for: 0.3, withTranslation: 10)
    passwordTextField.shake(count: 3, for: 0.3, withTranslation: 10)
    loginSuccess = false
    loginAlert(alertTitle: "Invalid Credentials", alertMsg: "Your  employee id or password is not correct")
  }
}
```

When i call test function **emploginSuccess()** method does not get called. Test function is executed successfully with out any error.
I thought that problem is ***empLoginDelegate*** is not initialised in my code, so i had tried possible ways to initialise it as self but nothing worked for me. Is there any other way to use delegation pattern in singleton class in swift3(iOS 10.3.1).

Comment: Did you try setting `CommunicationModule.sharedInstance.empLoginDelegate = self` from a method inside of `LoginViewController`?

Comment: Thank u vacawama for fast responding, its solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome.  I moved the comment to an answer.

Comment: Delegates are typically defined as weak to avoid a memory leak. Maybe you should check you "var empLoginDelegate" for this..

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion i will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are communicating with the singleton properly.  To set your instance of `LoginViewController` as the `empLoginDelegate`, call:

```
CommunicationModule.sharedInstance.empLoginDelegate = self
```

from a method inside of `LoginViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

**I think This method is good, for me that is best way**

```
final class Singleton {

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    //MARK: Shared Instance

    static let shared: Singleton = Singleton()

}
```